# Размер DIV в зависимости от размера окна

Tags: html, css

Имеем две колонки, левая к примеру 250px, правая в зависимости от размера окна, к примеру до 900px правая колонка 600px, если размер окна более 1100px размер правой колонки 900px. Без использования JS и т.д. Сам никак не могу разобраться.

P.S. Забыл совсем уточнить, что бы правая колонка не плавала. Т.е. ее размер либо 600px либо 900px, без промежуточных значений. Как в CSS фреймворках. Их не советуйте, т.к. занимаюсь самообразованием.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можешь использовать медиа запросы. 
Ты можешь задавать условия, при которых тот или иной блок будет принимать определённые стили.
В твоём примере если ширина окна 1100px то левой блок 250px а правый 900пикселей, но получается, что он не влезет, так как 900 + 250 =1150 пикселей и правый блок будет на новой строке. 
 Главное, чтобы ты понял, можно задавать в % , как в предыдущих примерах, а если тебе нужны конкретная ширина, то используй медиа запросы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    .div-1 {
        float: left;
        height: 500px;
        width: 250px;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .div-2 {
        /* Ширина по умолчанию */
        width: 500px; 
        float: left;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: orange;
    }

    /* Когда ширина окна до 900 пикселей, ширина  div-2 будет 600px */
    @media screen and (max-width: 900px){
        .div-2 {
            width: 600px;
        }
    }
    /* Когда ширина окна от 1100 пикселей, ширина  div-2 будет 900px */
    @media screen and (min-width: 1100px){
        .div-2 {
            width: 900px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

```
<body>
    <div class="div-1"></div>
    <div class="div-2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: ответили красиво ! но ещё бы не ТЫкали было бы ваще атас

Comment: А что не так с "ТЫ"? Читаю ответ, выглядит как будто знакомый мне напрямую объясняет как решить проблему )) все норм, главное что помог )

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так

## left{

```
width: 250px;
```

}

## right{

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 250px);
width:    -moz-calc(100% - 250px);
width:         calc(100% - 250px);
```

}​

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать CSS.
Вставляется в HTML. Пример ниже, адаптивный дизайн. Колонка занимает 66% ширины окна. При этом минимальное значение 600px, а максимальное 900px. В промежуточных значениях она плавающая под размер окна

```html
<style media="all">
 #element {
    width: 66%;
    max-width: 900px;
    min-width: 600px;
   }
</style>
```